# My app can't send a GET, OkHttp

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp

I have strange a problem.
I have service in `localhost:8080` and everything is good configured, I can open this service in browser using by Android device ( real, not emulator ). 
In my opinion I have something wrong in my code.

But in app i got `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080`

This is my code:

```
private void sendGET() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic("admin", "admin");
                return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
            }
        });

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://localhost:8080/users")
                .build();

        client.build().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.w("http", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.w("http", response.body().string());
            }
        });

    }
```

What can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be issues with how `localhost` is being mapped to an actual IP address.  Try using your actual IP address:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.0.1:8080/users")  // for example
            .build();
```

The above assumes an IP address of `192.168.0.1`.

To find your IP address, type `ipconfig` on Windows or `ifconfig` on Linux.

Comment: @companyn2 I would add that you when you put your app into production, you'll have to use an actual IP address anyway, so might as well start doing it now.